# ngOnInit() function not called after google Login in Angular4

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I am making a web application & user can Login through his/her credentials or via facebook & Gmail. Problem occurs when user **login through facebook or Gmail** as after Login I am redirecting user to Home Page & there **ngOninit() function is not called** so I am not able to call any API at initial Page Load. It works when I Login through credentials. What could be the possible reasons? Please help.

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core'; 
import {GlobalService} from '../services/global.service';
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor(private loginservice: LoginService, private globalService: GlobalService) {} 
ngOnInit() {this.loginservice.userDetails(this.globalService.user_token)
.subscribe((response: any) => { 
console.log(response);
}}
```

Comment: post your code here

Comment: `import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core'; import {GlobalService} from '../services/global.service';export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {constructor(private loginservice: LoginService,  private globalService: GlobalService) {}  ngOnInit() {this.loginservice.userDetails(this.globalService.user_token).subscribe((response: any) => { console.log(response);}}`. This Is my code for home.component.ts. I am redirecting to home path after google Login. I am not able to reach code inside ngOnInit while google Login

Answer (score 0):

I think **NgZone** will resolve the issue.

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core'; 
import {GlobalService} from '../services/global.service';
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private loginservice: LoginService, private globalService: 
GlobalService,private zone:NgZone) {} 

ngOnInit() {

if (this.globalService.user_token) {
this.zone.run(() =>
this.loginservice.userDetails(this.globalService.user_token)
 .subscribe((response: any) => { 
 console.log(response);
}
);
}
}
```

Comment: Even this didn't work ! As I mentioned ngOninit() is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Sunil, that worked for me.  As Mohit notes Cognito User Pool login worked fine, however gauth resulted in the ngInit() lifecycle event not being fired when router loaded the dashboard.

### Mohit - there is solution pertinent information here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18254.  Please see recent success with ActivatedRoute.

angular5 core/router 5.2.0, aws-amplify, gapi latest